# Advice needed on plotting relativey extremely small values

Tags: r, data-visualization, barplot

My problem is that I need somehow to visualize on one graph percentages of 0.1%, 2.5% and the remaining 97.4%. The only thing I can think of right now is a stacked bar chart with an `sqrt` transformation.

Is it a way to go? Aren't there any other ways to represent such data? What does your experience say?

Would be grateful for any hint or suggestion :).

(I'm using R and ggplot if that matters)

Comment: Maybe a log scale instead of a sqrt using `scale_y_log10()` in `ggplot`? Do you have any example dataset to see how this looks like?

Comment: @AntoniosK, I though about log -- but log10(0.25) will produce a negative value, and if to show that data as a whole (0.001 + 0.025 + 0.974 = 1 or 100%), then how to display negative values?

Comment: Maybe you can shift values up by a comstant if it's for visualisation purposes, but a sqrt transformation won't have this problem and might be better.

Comment: @AntoniosK, yeah, I haven't thought about shifting... that may be interesting, thanks :).

Comment: Do you have the original counts this proportions were calculated from? Then plot this instead, look at the R (CRAN) package vcd (visualizing categorical data) do this: library(vcd)     example(rootogram)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks! Yes, I have original numbers... And log10 may be even better then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With three numbers of disparate sizes you may be better off with a table instead of a graph. If you have to transform, you're starting to loose some of the benefit of visual encoding, especially for parts to whole.

However, 1:1000 is possibly within range of using area for visual encoding with a treemap or bubble chart. It provides a similar affect of a sqrt transformation but now your eyes are in on it, too. Not as accurate as 1-D measures like position and bar length, but not terrible for rough judgments.

[image]

[image]

Another option is a inset view, which is really adding a second chart that replicates the small values at a better scale.